# how using SQL IN operator in find method of cakephp ORM

Tags: cakephp, orm, find, in-operator

i am beginner in cakephp , and i want use SQL `IN` operator in find method , i have words table.
my code is :

```
$this->Word->find('Word.wordid in (83,82)');
```

, and this code create this query :

```
SELECT `Userword`.`userwordid`, `Userword`.`userid`, `Userword`.`wordid`, 
`Userword`.`date`, `Userword`.`levelid` FROM `userwords` AS `Userword` WHERE 
`Userword`.`wordid` = (82)
```

but i need this query

```
SELECT `Userword`.`userwordid`, `Userword`.`userid`, `Userword`.`wordid`, 
Userword`.`date`, `Userword`.`levelid` FROM `userwords` AS `Userword` WHERE 
`Userword`.`wordid` IN (83,82)
```

how can getting like this query (using IN operator )
thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you need to let cake take care of that - simply use it as it was a string (but make sure it is an array):

```
$arrayOfIds = [1, 5, ...];
$this->Word->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Word.wordid' => $arrayOfIds)
));
```

Comment: Note that this is only valid for CakePHP <= 2.x. In 3.x you will need to manually add IN again: `'Word.wordid IN' => $arrayOfIds`

Comment: not working
it build query like `SELECT `User`.`email`, `User`.`id` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`specialization_id` = '26,19'`

Comment: `$allUsers = $this->Query->User->find('all', array(
                    'fields' => array('User.email', 'User.email'),
                    'conditions' => array('User.specialization_id' => $specializationId)
                ));`

Comment: You didnt use an array!