# Strange behaviour of IN clause in Cakephp 2.8.2

Tags: php, behavior, clause, cakephp-2.8

I have created multiple checkbox as follow.

```
 $forms  = $this->wondr->m('WApplication.ApplicantForms')->find('list', array('conditions' => array('facility_id' => $this->wondr->facility['Facility']['id']), 'contain' => array()));

    $event->result['forms'] = $event->subject()->Form->input(
            'forms', array(
                'multiple'   => 'checkbox',
                'options' => $forms,
                'class'  => 'form-control',
                'label'  => __('Forms'),
            )
       );
```

It works fine when I chose multiple check box but when I chose only single check box it throws error

```
   $forms  = $this->wondr->m('WApplication.ApplicantForms')->find('list', array('conditions' => array('facility_id' => $this->wondr->facility['Facility']['id'],
        'ApplicantForms.id IN '=> $event->data['requestQuery']['forms']
    ), 'contain' => array()));
```

CakePHP automatically converting IN() to IN = () for single id.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= ('595b5fab-97d4-4c59-a41a-013fac120009')' at line 1

SQL Query: SELECT `ApplicantForms`.`id`, `ApplicantForms`.`name` FROM `wondr`.`applicant_forms` AS `ApplicantForms` WHERE `facility_id` = '58ecb98f-92cc-4a90-a692-0026ac120005' AND `ApplicantForms`.`id` IN = ('595b5fab-97d4-4c59-a41a-013fac120009')
```

Can somebody please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try getting rid of the `IN`, and make sure that `$event->data['requestQuery']['forms']` is an array.

Comment: $event->data['requestQuery']['forms'] is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

```
$forms  = $this->wondr->m('WApplication.ApplicantForms')->find('list', array('conditions' => array('facility_id' => $this->wondr->facility['Facility']['id'],
    'ApplicantForms.id IN '=> $event->data['requestQuery']['forms']
), 'contain' => array()));
```

By:

```
$forms  = $this->wondr->m('WApplication.ApplicantForms')->find('list', array('conditions' => array('facility_id' => $this->wondr->facility['Facility']['id'],
    'ApplicantForms.id'=> (array)$event->data['requestQuery']['forms']
), 'contain' => array()));
```

In other words, remove the `IN` and make sure that `$event->data['requestQuery']['forms']` is an array (if you have a doubt, you could first `var_dump` it).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445104/978690